# How to call function with variables of a form

Tags: function, vba, ms-access

I have a form named ContactsForm with a button at the bottom. Once its clicked, it runs an event procedure.

```
Public Function GET_MESGS(Message As String, Number As String) As String
    Dim Message As String
    Dim Number As String
....
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Call GET_MESGS
End Sub
```

But once its click it just throws me an error. Obviously I'm not calling the function correctly. I want to call the function with values from the form.

Answer (score 2):

Since the sub needs 2 parameters, you need to call GET_MESGS with 2 paramters:

For example:

```
Sub Command1_Click()

  Call GET_MESGS("ABC","2345")

 End Sub
```

To use values from the form, use something like this:

```
Call GET_MESGS(textbox1.Text, Label1.Text)
```

Comment: If you still getting erros, please specify the error message.

Comment: Thanks SNash, but instead of ABC, how do I call the values from a the form?

Comment: If for example your values are in a text box you could use `Call GET_MESGS(textbox1.value, textbox2.value)`

Comment: something like this:

Call GET_MESGS(textbox1.Text, Label1.Text)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you to all of you guys. I can't appreciate it enough!!